# lazy matching and optional character in regex

Tags: java, regex

Consider these two urls:

```
http:website.com/?q=hello
http:website.com/?q=hello&z=world
```

I would like to match the part after the query url parameter `q=` and (possibly) before another `&`. That is, I would like to match `hello` in the first string, and `hello` in the second.

I am using the regex `\?q=(.+?)&` but this of course fails to match the first `hello` that is not preceded by `&`.

Trying to make the `&` optional with `\?q=(.+?)&?` does not work either.

I do not understand what is the issue.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the second match be `hellod`?

Comment: haha good catch bro

Comment: Instead of `(.+?)`, you can match any character that is not a `&` with `([^&]+)`.

Comment: its actually a very good trick